# How to speed up restore process with gziped LVM?

Tags: backup, lvm, restore

I am experimenting with creating/restoring backups with the help of LVM. It works, but the restore process takes about 8 min. on an idel XEON with 32GB RAM and SSD. The system does not even seam to swett according to htop and top with processor almost idle but resulting in only 45.7 MB/s on SSDs.

How can speed up the process? The restore looks like this:

```
$ sudo gunzip -c snap_vol1-20150904_055547.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/vg0/staging

41738240+0 records in
41738240+0 records out
21369978880 bytes (21 GB) copied, 468.036 s, 45.7 MB/s
```

Answer (score 1):

Some quick things to check:

First of all, if you are working on a single disk you have a throughput of 90MB/s. Depending on the disk and the interface this may actually be what the disk is capable of(!)

By default, DD makes many very small writes. You can use the BS option (as in bs=1M) to increase the block size, which will reduce the number of writes, which in turn should reduce the IO load.

Sending the data over a pipe is semi-expensive, as the data has to be copied into a relatively small buffer and out again, in addition to the context switches between gunzip (which by the way is singlethreaded, another bottleneck) and dd. Try unpacking the file first, and then dd it, and measure the time each operation takes for an idea of what is slowing you down.

Answer (score 0):

Gunzip is a single thread process, and even with fast processors it often top out at 40/50 MB/s.

You have two possibilities:

- use a faster compressor, as lzop or lz4
- use a multithread gzip implementation as pigz (see http://zlib.net/pigz/
  )

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried lz4 and received 104MB/s while compressing on a VM running on a Macbook Pro. Will now upload to server to test decompressing speed.

Comment: Unfortunatelly restore seems not to be possible. The system asks me for a file type. After specifying I get: sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/vg0/staging /home/data/bricks/brick2/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg0-staging,

Comment: It is very strange. Have you decompressed the lz4 archive before using dd to write it to the disks? Anyway, can you try with pigz?